# How to fix Client Protocol Exception with Exchange Web Services (EWS)

Tags: java, android, http-post, exchangewebservices

I have a problem with accessing Exchange Web Services (EWS) using:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost)
```

Most of the time this works, but sometimes I get a ClientProtocolException.

In the research I've done, I can see that we need to provide exception handling for `ClientProtocolException`, but I haven't been able to find out why I'm getting this exception and how to fix it.

Does anyone know what this Exception is and the best way to code for it?  Or is this just a problem with the EWS site I'm accessing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Check if request sent using http or https. this error occurs when request is unable to communicate with iis certificates.